# An overflow error message from `awesome_cossim_topn`

Tags: python-3.x

I am using `awesome_cossim_topn` function from Python module `sparse_dot_topn` (https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn/blob/master/sparse_dot_topn/awesome_cossim_topn.py). The arguments I passed to the function are as following.

```
cosine_matrix = awesome_cossim_topn(
  A = matrixA,
  B = matrixA.transpose(),
  ntop = vals.size,
  lower_bound = 0.8,
  use_threads = True,
  n_jobs = 8
)
```

Particularly, `matrixA` is a `170000 x 1900000` matrix, and `vals.size = 170000`.

I got the following error:

```
OverflowError: value too large to convert to int
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is the matrix dimension is too big: `170000 x 1900000 = 323000000000`.